# do something for first foreach and something else for all others?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a custom gallery in Wordpress that shows an image for the first gallery item and texts for all other items.

I've come up with the following, but this only outputs the first item and nothing for the others.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo 'the first one';
    }
    if ( $i !== 0) {
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, 0, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, 0, false, false);
        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
        }
        $output .= 'Images: ' . count($attachments);
        $output .= "
                <br style='clear: both;' />
             </div>\n";

        return $output;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing `return $output;` - which is stopping the whole thing right there.

Try `echo $output;` instead. Otherwise I think you've got it.

As another response pointed out, you also have some syntax errors. e.g. on this line missing an opening curly brace `{`:

```
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
```

You'll also need to clear the $output variable. Set `$output = '';` at the start of the loop each time through, otherwise you'll just keep appending to `$output` and get your results repeated.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the curly bracket but when I use echo instead of return, I get the results appearing 4 times. The first shows the 2nd item in the array, the second the 2nd and 3rd items in the array, the third the 2nd, 3rd and 4th items, and then the final one shows all items.

Comment: You need to clear the `$output` variable. Set the `$output = '';` at the start of the loop each time through.

Comment: That's getting me closer - now I'm seeing the correct output ("the first one" + the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th items), but I'm also still seeing the final output (as above) that shows all items.

Comment: That must be something WordPress is doing further down. It does not appear to be happening because of anything in the snippet you pasted. I would read up on WordPress plugins and see if you, maybe, need to return something instead of echoing it out. Try `ob_start();` before everything and `return ob_get_clean();` at the end of your function, for example. Kind of hack, but might work?

Answer (score 1):

This line lacks an opening curly brace :

```
if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
```

Then your **for** loop end just before `$i++` and *$i* is never incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a function and then you can echo the function  inside your template and

something like in your functions.php

```
   function countimages($id)
    {
    $i = 0;
    $countthem = count($attachments); //count them
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo 'the first one';
        }
        if ( $i !== 0) {
            $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, 0, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, 0, false, false);
            $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
            $output .= "
                <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                    $link
                </{$icontag}>";
            if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
                $output .= "
                    <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                    " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                    </{$captiontag}>";
            }
            $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
            if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
                $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
            }
            $output .= 'Images: ' . count($attachments);
            $output .= "
                    <br style='clear: both;' />
                 </div>\n";

            return $output;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    }
then echo it inside your template page
$id=the_ID();
echo countimages($id);
```

Comment: This is already par of a larger function that outputs the whole gallery.

Comment: you want to count total no of attachment to a particular  post?can you try with this much code ??` $id=the_ID();
$total_attachments = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' && ID=$id");
echo $total_attachments;`